# bash: split pipe stream into records and combine all lines in a record into one

Tags: json, xml, bash, awk

I have a file containing a million individual xml files (simply concatenated) that I would like to convert to json. The file looks like this:

```
<amf xmlns="...">
 <test>
   1 content
 </test>
</amf>
<amf xmlns="...">
 <test>
   2 content
 </test>
</amf>
```

Note that the above file is not a properly formatted xml file (i.e. the individual entries are not nested), so I cannot convert it using `xml2json'.

To achieve this I want to separate the file into records, so that each record corresponds to the individual xml file, concatenate the xml file into one line, and then use `parallel` on each line applying `xml2json` to achieve `json` output.

When I try to use `awk` or `gawk` on OSX, I have trouble splitting the pipe into records. Here's the code I tried ("useless" cat is for readability):

```
cat bigfile.xml | awk '{print NR "<amf xml"$0}' RS="<amf xml"
```

Which gives:

```
1<amf xml
2<amf xmlns="...">
 <test>
   1 content
 </test>
</amf>

3<amf xmlns="...">
 <test>
   2 content
 </test>
</amf>
```

It's easy to remove the first 'record', but I can't collapse the output of the other records into one line for each record. I tried experimenting with FS="\n" and OFS=" " without much luck.

Can you help me output these records on one line per record?

Comment: Wrap the file into `<root>...</root>` and use `xml2json`.

Comment: Thank you, @choroba, I tried that, but xml2json quits with error. Possibly it's because the file contains roughly 10 million lines, so xml2json has trouble processing that.

Comment: Then I'd use a pull or SAX parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT:

```
$ awk -v RS='</amf>\n' '{$1=$1; ORS=RT}1' file
<amf xmlns="..."> <test> 1 content </test></amf>
<amf xmlns="..."> <test> 2 content </test></amf>
```

Comment: This works with `gawk` on OSX and avoids giving the first empty result. I tried using the closing tag as the record separator, but somehow couldn't get it to work, so this is very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `$1=$1` appears to have solved my problem:

```
awk '{$1=$1; print NR "<amf xml"$0}' RS="<amf xml" bigfile.xml
```

I still have to get rid of the first line manually, but this seems to be OK.

```
1<amf xml
2<amf xmlns="...">  <test>    1 content  </test> </amf> 
3<amf xmlns="...">  <test>    2 content  </test> </amf>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
$ awk -v RS='<amf xml' 'NF{$1=$1; print RS $0}' file
```